# Zombie processes in Docker also with init / tini system

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, centos7, zombie-process

**Problem**
Docker containers started via Jenkins pipeline command

```
docker.image(imageToStart).inside('--init')
```

can not be stopped due to zombie processes left by container.

**Questions**

- How is it possible to get zombie processes from a Docker container, when it was started with
   '--init' option?
- Has someone else hit the same issue?

**Used environment**

- Docker 18.03.1-ce
- Jenkins 2.60.2
- Docker Pipeline plugin 1.12

**Details**
When a container is started from Jenkins pipeline with a command like:

```
docker.image('alpine').inside('--init') {
  sh ('ps -efa -o pid,ppid,user,comm')
}
```

There are several processes in this container with parent PID 0:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
loco does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:1002 \
  --init \
  -w /lhome/ci<br>admin/jenkins/workspace/bli-groovy-test \
  -v /lhome/ciadmin/jenkins/workspace/bli-groovy-test:/lhome/ciadmin/jenkins/workspace/bli-groovy-test:rw,z \
  -v /lhome/ciadmin/jenkins/workspace/bli-groovy-test-tmp:/lhome/ciadmin/jenkins/workspace/bli-groovy-test-tmp:rw,z \
  -e ******** \
  --entrypoint cat alpine
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh

[bli-groovy-test] Running shell script
+ ps -efa -o pid,ppid,user,comm
PID   PPID  USER     COMMAND
    1     0 1001     init
    7     1 1001     cat
    8     0 1001     sh
   14     8 1001     script.sh
   15    14 1001     ps
[Pipeline] }
```

- PID 1 / PPID 0 is the 'init' command used to start the container
- PID 8 / PPID 0 is the 'sh' command from the closure to execute 'ps' command

The 'sh' process does not reap its child processes. When the process itself exits its descendants are assigned to a PPID from outside the container and **not** to PPID 1 from the 'init' process of the container.
The new parent PID is the PID of the 'docker-containerd-shim' process of the container.

With the small example I could not reproduce the zombie processes, but here is the situation from a more complex Jenkins job:

**Docker command from Jenkins job**

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:1002 \
  --init \
  -w /lhome/testadmin/jenkins-coreloops/workspace/test-job/database \
  -v /lhome/testadmin/jenkins-coreloops/workspace/test-job/database:/lhome/testadmin/jenkins-coreloops/workspace/test-job/database:rw,z \
  -v /lhome/testadmin/jenkins-coreloops/workspace/test-job/database-tmp:/lhome/testadmin/jenkins-coreloops/workspace/test-job/database-tmp:rw,z \
  -e ******** \
  --entrypoint cat richmond.lhs-systems.com:5000/ait/mpde
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
10:03:09 [database] Running shell script
10:03:09 + ./db-upgrade.sh
```

- inside the container shell scripts are started
- shell scripts call perl scripts
- perl scripts start SQL*Plus (1 instance per database login)
- perl scripts send SQL commands to SQL*Plus instances via STDIN

When the closure ends and Jenkins tries to stop the container, the following processes are left:

```
[testadmin@testhost] ~  # ps -efa | grep -vw grep | grep -w 47077
root      1725 47077  0 10:03 ?        00:00:00 [ps] <defunct>
root      1732 47077  0 10:03 ?        00:00:00 [docker-runc] <defunct>
root      2887 47077  0 10:04 ?        00:00:00 [sqlplus] <defunct>
root      2915 47077  0 10:04 ?        00:00:00 [sqlplus] <defunct>
root     47077 17349  0 10:03 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd-shim 
                                                -namespace moby 
                                                -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/1863503ca54f75168db8ce20c78b821c0e5280f07d59875e8f651db4f0b67d9f 
                                                -address /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 
                                                -containerd-binary /usr/bin/docker-containerd 
                                                -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root     47098 47077  0 10:03 pts/0    00:00:00 /dev/init -- cat
root     47506 47077  0 10:03 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>
[testadmin@testhost] ~  #
```

and command 'docker stop' is aborted after timeout of 180 seconds.

To cleanup the remaining processes of the container this docker-containerd-shim process has to be killed with SIGKILL.

**Note**
We observed this issue on our recently installed CentOS server:
- CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- environment related parts from 'docker info':

```
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 48
Total Memory: 377.6GiB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The behavior on other of our Docker hosts is similar with respect to the multiple processes with parent PID 0, but we didn't observe that containers were hanging on shutdown or that there was a similar number of zombie processes.
For comparisation the similar 'docker info' extract from one of these other hosts:

```
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: dock-thinpool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
 Base Device Size: 16.11GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 48
Total Memory: 377.6GiB
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

**Edit 2018-Aug-01:**

As workaround I added the init process as subreaper also to problematic *'docker exec'* calls and problematic *'sh'* calls in the Jenkins docker().inside() closure.
This eliminated the zombie processes in our environment.